# Where is this while loop ending?

Tags: loops, while-loop

I came across this code about regular expression online. I am not able to comprehend when is the outer while loop ending/breaking?

```
 while (true) {    
            System.out.println("Enter regex pattern:");  
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(sc.nextLine());    
            System.out.println("Enter text:");  
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sc.nextLine());    
            boolean found = false;    
            while (matcher.find()) {    
                System.out.println("I found the text "+matcher.group()+" starting at index "+    
                 matcher.start()+" and ending at index "+matcher.end());    
                found = true;    
            }    
            if(!found){    
                System.out.println("No match found.");    
            }    
        }
```

Please Explain!

Comment: I haven't used Java in years, but for what its worth, it doesn't look like the code is breaking out of the loop.  I would imagine the author intended to check the sc object for an end-of-line state, and break on that, but just forgot.

Comment: `while (true)` would never end or break (unless) a `break;` is specified. the current state of the code, this would run until you exit the application

Comment: @Clinton How he would have done that? (check the sc object for an end-of-line state)?